# API REST en Visual Basic + Cliente Windows Forms (VB.NET)

Tags: vb.net, api, rest, restful, webapi

He hecho un proyecto de prueba que va a hacer de API REST con las siguientes características:

- Aplicación web ASP.NET (Visual basic)
- .NET Framework 4.7.2
- Al crear la aplicación, elijo: API Web (Sin HTTPS)
- Una vez creada:

  - Agregar nuevo elemento "ADO.NET Entity Data Model"
  - Code First desde Base de Datos
  - Configuro la conexión y agrego todas las tablas

En este punto he creado un controlador de prueba para una de las tablas, lo que me permite conectarme desde Postman (lo he probado un poco y funciona bien) a:

http://localhost:54541/api/usuarios

Hasta aquí, creo que todo bien.

Mi problema viene ahora. La idea de este proyecto (que va a ser mi PFG) es que haga de servicio, y aparte crear un segundo proyecto tipo "Aplicación Windows Forms" que haga de cliente.

Para hacer esto último, he probado a crear una aplicación de Windows Forms y agregar un origen de datos de tipo "Servicio", pero no consigo "ver" al otro proyecto.

¿Cómo debería hacer esto?

He estado haciendo búsquedas en internet acerca de esto, pero lo poco que encuentro no me acaba de ayudar. Además, la mayoría de las cosas estan en C# y no me aclaro.

Ojalá alguien me pueda echar una mano.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Aunque me siento estúpido y tentado de, simplemente, eliminar mi pregunta, he pensado que igual algún día otro novato como yo pasa por la misma situación y puede que esto le ayude.

La respuesta es que no hace falta añadir ningún origen de datos. Las dos aplicaciones no se van a comunicar como se comunicaría una aplicación de Windows Forms con una base de datos, sino a través de URLs y el uso de verbos http (Get, Put, Post y Delete)

Como ejemplo, he hecho (en la aplicación que hace de cliente) una clase Usuario:

```
Friend Class Usuario
    Public Property Id() As Integer
    Public Property Nombre() As String
    Public Property Login() As String
    Public Property Pass() As String
    Public Property Acceso() As Boolean
End Class
```

Por otro lado, en el archivo Form1.vb creo un método de prueba que me permite recuperar los usuarios:

```
Imports System.IO
Imports System.Net
Imports Newtonsoft.Json

Public Class Form1
    Private Async Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        Dim respuesta As String = Await GetHttp("Usuarios")
        Dim lst As List(Of MayteJiji.Usuario) = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(Of List(Of MayteJiji.Usuario))(respuesta)
        DataGridView1.DataSource = lst
    End Sub

    Private Async Function GetHttp(entidad As String) As Task(Of String)
        Dim oRequest As WebRequest = WebRequest.Create("http://localhost:54541/api/" + entidad)
        Dim oResponse As WebResponse = oRequest.GetResponse()
        Dim sr As StreamReader = New StreamReader(oResponse.GetResponseStream())
        Return Await sr.ReadToEndAsync()
    End Function
End Class
```

Esto es solo una prueba. Lo ideal será separar el método GetHttp y llevarlo a otra clase en la que implementemos los métodos para Get, Get/id, Post, Put y Delete, así como cualesquiera otros que podamos necesitar.